# tracking user login with django

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using the builtin login module to perform logins in my website

`url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'extra_context': {'page_name': 'login'}),`

and this is the next action of my login form

`<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/redirect/">`

During registration I create a small tracking code for the user like this:

```
host = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','') or request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
if tid == '0':
    import os, binascii
    tid = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(6))
ut = UserTracking.objects.create(user=user, username=username, tracking_id=tid, remote_host=host, action='register')
ut.save()
variables = RequestContext(request, {'username': form.cleaned_data['username'], 'email': form.cleaned_data['email'], 'message': message, 'tid': tid})
return render_to_response('registration/register_success.html', variables)
```

In the `register_success.html` I use a jquery plugin to save my tracking code into the user's pc like this:

`$.jStorage.set('tid', '{{ tid }}');`

How can I add this code to my login form and send in with username and password to my `views.py`?

Comment: Using [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#login-and-logout-signals) could be more directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to customize the login view.

1. Add your login view:

   url(r'^login/$', 'myapp.account.views.login', {'extra_context': {'page_name': 'login'})

Then in your myapp/account/views.py, add:

```
def login(request, template_name='logintemplate.html'):

    if (request.POST):
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        tracking_code = request.POST.get('tracking_code', None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
......
    if user:
        # your custom code here
......
```

and in logintemplate.html add the tracking code into the login form.